# RC4 Not generating the proper scrambled state array

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, rc4-cipher

I have the follow code below to generate a scrambled state array, however, it does not seem to be generating the properly randomized state array for the key (51323).

```cpp
unsigned char* generateStateArray(unsigned long key) {
    unsigned char s[256];
    //Load the state array from 1-255
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        s[i] = i;
    }

    //Get the binary representation of the key
    unsigned long n = key;

    int binary[64];
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        binary[i] = 0;
        std::cout << binary[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; n > 0; i++) {
        binary[i] = n % 2;
        n /= 2;
    }

    //Randomize the entries
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        j = (j + binary[i % 64] + s[i]) & 255;

        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = c;    
    }
}
```

The output for S should look like:

[image: Output]

But it gives me this output:

[image: my output]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: I *thought* RC4 discards the first several hundred bytes of the sequence to avoid a startup bias. Are you discarding the bytes? What test vectors are you using?

Comment: @jww This is a very elementary school project, so I am not discarding any bytes.

Comment: So you aren't implementing RC4, so the table in your book doesn't apply.

Comment: The book gave the exact instructions for the RC4 cipher though

Comment: The code only seems to implement the [initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Key-scheduling_algorithm_(KSA)) of the S-Boxes. The key `51323` may be encoded incorrectly into the `binary`-array. Is the encoding to be used described in more detail in the instructions?

Comment: @jww: RC4 does *not* discard any bytes following the runup. That was simply an unofficial patch added after the fact in an attempt to fix some critical weaknesses.

Comment: FWIW, the key to RC4 is normally specified as an array of bytes.